# too many indices error in python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I write some test code like below, I get "too many indices error".

I don't know why this code doesn't work...

```
a = np.arange(40).reshape(4,10)
print a
in_ = np.array(a, dtype=np.float32)
print in_
in_ = in_[:,:,::-1]
print in_
```

Comment: in_ = in_[:,:-1] should be like this

Comment: On what line do you get the error? I would guess it is `in_[:,:,::-1]`, but I guess the real issue is what are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to modify image file with pixel level.

Answer (score 0):

My original test code is below. I miss when I make test array.

```
im = Image.open('/data/synthia/RGB/ap_000_02-11-2015_18-02-19_000162_2_Rand_6.png')
in_ = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
in_ = in_[:,:,::-1]
in_ -= np.array((104.00698793,116.66876762,122.67891434))
in_ = in_.transpose((2,0,1))
```

Comment: Looks like `im` here is a 3d array.  What is its `shape`.  In your question you created a 2d array, not a 3d one.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `.reshape(4,10)` you transform your array into a 2d array sized 4x10. This array has 2 dimensions thus it has 2 indices only.

When you call `[:,:,::-1]` you mention 3 incides for your 2d array: `:`, `:` and `::-1`. It causes the error.